# How can i add event listener to the content of dojo editor?

Tags: dojo

I am working with dojo editor. And I have a problem so could you help me to solve this 
problem.

My problem is: how can I add event listener to  tag that I input to the editor such as onClick, onMouseover, etc...

For Example : I input an image tag to the editor content:

```
var ed=dijit.byId("myEditor"); //my editor has id id myEditor
var img = "<img src='myPic.jpg' alt='' id='myPic'/>"; //my image tag
ed.forcus();
ed.execCommand("inserthtml", img); //insert image tag into editor content
```

After inserting image tag to the editor, now I want to add "click" event to it, because i want click that image and a small tooltip showed to choose align that image left or right.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/j475Q/

Basically the node you want to connect is `editor.editNode`:

```
var editor = dijit.byId("editor");
dojo.connect(editor.editNode, "ondblclick", this, "_onDblClick");
```

Afterwards, in `_onDblClick` method you have to find out which kind of node was dblclicked and decide whether to proceed with an action:

```
_onDblClick: function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    var tag = target.tagName ? target.tagName.toLowerCase() : "";
    if(tag == "img") {        
        dojo.withGlobal(editor.window, "selectElement", selectionapi, [target]);
    }
}
```

I found this in the `LinkDialog` plugin (dijit/_editor/plugins/LinkDialog.js). Look there for more inspiration.

Comment: BTW the code in jsFiddle is everything you need to align an image left or right. The code selects the image and when selected the standard toolbar align buttons apply also to the image.