# Force click on <img> tag to select wrapping <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink, dojo

This is in the context of a Dojo editor, but it should apply more generally.

I have an `<img>` tagged that is wrapped in a `<a>` tag:

```
<a><img width="146" height="109" src="/gaggleVideoProxy.do?op=thumb&amp;thumbUrl=http://i.ytimg.com/vi/xoZXdWl7BZs/default.jpg" _djrealurl="/gaggleVideoProxy.do?op=thumb&amp;thumbUrl=http://i.ytimg.com/vi/xoZXdWl7BZs/default.jpg" &ytvideoid="xoZXdWl7BZs&amp;userVideoId=1073344&quot;"></a>
```

If you click on this, the image is selected.  Clicking the delete key will cause the image to be deleted, but leaves the link tag.

I'm looking for a way to ensure that the `<a>` tag is deleted whenever the `<img>` tag is deleted.

---

*Update*

This turns out to be more of a dojo api question.  Looking at this SO question/answer has given me the basic tools to do what I need:

[How can i add event listener to the content of dojo editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291637/how-can-i-add-event-listener-to-the-content-of-dojo-editor)

Comment: Post your JavaScript code. Should just be a matter of calling the delete method on the parent node.

Comment: I haven't got any javascript worth posting yet.  I'm looking for a way to either: 1) capture the delete event on the `<img>` and then delete the <a> or 2) force the `<a>` tag to be selected when `<img>` is selected (so that delete will affect `<a>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
_connectTagEvents: function(){
    this.editor.onLoadDeferred.addCallback(dojo.hitch(this, function(){
  this.connect(this.editor.editNode, "onclick", this._onClick);
    }));
},
_onClick: function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  var tag = target.tagName ? target.tagName.toLowerCase() : "";
  var wrapper = target.parentNode;

  if(/* TAG and/or WRAPPER are what you want*/) {        
    dojo.withGlobal(this.editor.window, "selectElement", dijit._editor.selection, [wrapper]);
  }
}
```

And this will force the wrapping element to be selected.  (Don't forget to call `_connectTagEvents` from the `initButton()` method.

Comment: I think you may end up screwing the change history if you do it that way... You may be able to do that by overriding LinkDialog::_getCurrentValues instead (didn't try... just a thought)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the image, delete the image's parent node.

Comment: How?  I was trying to capture the onclick event on the <img> and then call focus() on the <a>, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: are you using jQuery or raw Javascript? If you use jQuery this might become very easy to solve.

Comment: Using Dojo.  I can do anything in Dojo that can be done in jQuery, so I'm all ears.

Comment: How do you capture the delete event?